# SVG needs to fill empty space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I have two SVGs containing d3 charts. Every time I click a button the top (yellow) svg is removed and a new one is inserted above it;

```
d3.select("#svg_comp").remove()
DrawComponentChart()
```

The previous svg_comp is removed and the other SVG, which should always remain there, is not. Which is good. The only problem is the space occupied by the SVG which was removed from the page is not filled the svg below;

[image]

How can I get rid of this space, or get the lowest svg (currently empty) to occupy it? THe contents of the SVGs are D3.js charts.

EDIT:

```
            var svg_bad = d3.select("#broken-chart-space").insert("svg", "svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                .attr("id", "svg_bad");
```

Is used to position and insert new SVGs

Comment: You're probably using absolute placement for the SVG below or something like that.

Comment: @Lars what do you mean?

Comment: How are you positioning the element that contains the second chart?

Comment: @LARS i use theb above code in the EDIT for both SVGs

Comment: Ok and how are those container elements you're selecting positioned?

Comment: @lars i'm not sure if I do. i think i just insert and let it add them for me. here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6hcyqrn3/ of the function

Comment: Then the lower graph should move up, see http://jsfiddle.net/bcgoovem/1/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. But you may try .exit().remove() on the previous elements and change the new elements' positioning.